# Unique Data Frame by Prioritize Value in R

Tags: r, unique, subset

I have the following data frame in R:

```
A<-c(1,0,0,1,0)
B<-c("A","A","B","B","C")
df<-cbind(A,B)
```

and i want unique this data frame by prioritize a value in column A.
Prioritize a value of 1 rather than a value of 0.

I tried to write the code as follows:

```
uniq<-unique(subset(df, df[,1]==1))
```

and result:

```
      A   B  
[1,] "1" "A"
[2,] "1" "B"
```

But i want:

```
      A   B
[1,] "1" "A"
[2,] "1" "B"
[3,] "0" "C"
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks before

Comment: Where are other 0 rows?

Comment: On column A. I tried to write uniq<-unique(subset(df, df[,1]==1 | df[,1]==0))
But the result is all rows of data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `df` is actually a matrix so you could start by `df <- data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Then sort so that A == 1 comes first and finally weed out duplicates

```
df <- df[order(df[["A"]], decreasing = TRUE), ]
df[!duplicated(df[["B"]]), ]
  A B
1 1 A
4 1 B
5 0 C
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate`, if you make sure you have a data frame and not a matrix:

```
df<-data.frame(A,B, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)    
aggregate(A ~ B, df,  max)
#   B A
# 1 A 1
# 2 B 1
# 3 C 0
```

If you want to prioritize a value and simple sorting isn't good enough (because you want to prioritize a character or factor value, or a numeric value that is not a min/max or you want to leave the order of other values intact), you can use :

```
df2 <- df[order(df$A!=1),]
df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2[["B"]]), ]
```

which is a minor twist on @snoram's answer

Comment: `data.frame` doesn't tidy the mess completely as column B becomes a factor in this case (OP might not care or want it this way but better be aware of it) :)

Answer (score 0):

First sort the data by the first column (decreasing order), then remove rows with duplicate value for second column.

```
df <- df[order(df[,1], decreasing = T),]
df[duplicated(df[,2])==F,]

     A   B  
[1,] "1" "A"
[2,] "1" "B"
[3,] "0" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with the help of Data table you will be able to do it

```
A<-c(1,0,0,1,0)
B<-c("A","A","B","B","C")
df<-as.data.frame(as.character(cbind(A,B)))

df1<- dplyr::arrange(df,desc(A),B)

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df1)
setkey(DT, B)

d<- DT[J(unique(B)), mult = "last"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**tidyverse solution**

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% as.data.frame( stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) %>% 
  arrange( B, desc(A) ) %>%
  filter( !duplicated(B) )

#   A B
# 1 1 A
# 2 1 B
# 3 0 C
```